# jQuery > Word counter: Get increasing counter value when deleting words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using textarea to get comments and everything.

Text area that I use has word limits or `maxlength` of words. Now I will let users know that how many characters you can type more.

Though this is success till now, But i've got a problem in refreshing the counter values. It doesn't show refreshed value of counter as soon as i delete characters.
Also when i do keyup then counter shows old value from where i started deleting characters.

Now if textarea is empty and i type something then counter works good.

I have got a fiddle here-

[Text area counter](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/47a7A/53/)

Steps to reproduce-

1. Type a longer sentence.
2. Now delete this sentence from textarea.
3. Delete all texts from textarea and start typing again, it starts from full length of words.

counter is not showing refreshed values after deleting.

This is some code of jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text_max = 300;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

    $('#textarea').keypress(function() {
        var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using keypress, use keyup event.

In Chrome and IE the keypress event will be fired only when keys which can be displayed are pressed. Key like backspace and delete do not have a display property so keypress event will not get fired.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text_max = 300;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2vzZH/)

Comment: @Manoz it looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

I've had this one before!

Trick is to use `keyup()` instead of `keypress()`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47a7A/54/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it to capture all changes.
Also, I would change the HTML to have a default of 300 or whatever number to start and then wrap the counter value you are changing in another element and only change its value through this function.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    //Don't search for it over and over again
    var $cachedSelector = $('#textarea_feedback');
    var $cachedTextArea = $('#textarea');

    //Common function you can call repeatedly that only updates the counter
    function changeTextArea(){

        var text_length = $cahcedTextArea.val().length;

        var text_remaining = 300 - text_length;

        $cachedSelector.html(text_remaining);
   }

    //Handles Keyup or typing events
    $cachedTextArea.keyup(function() {
        changeTextArea()
    });

    //Handles common chage events like if someone copy/pastes into your input
    $cachedTextArea.change(function() {
        changeTextArea()
    });
});
```